# What is the definition of correct significant digits?

Tags: decimal-expansion, rounding-error

When I read the book "Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms", I came to the concept "correct significant digits" which I really can't understand.

The definition in the book is

> Here is a possible definition of correct significant digits:
>   *an approximation x' to x has p correct significant digits if x' and x round to the same number to p significant digits*.
>   Rounding is the act of replacing a given number by the nearest ...

I was confused with the description of x' and x round to the same number to p significant digits.

Does that mean the absolute value of x' minus x, and the significant digits of the absolute value is the correct significant digits?
I googled it but there was nothing else helped. 
Could any one give me an example, or more precise description? Thanks, guys.

---

Editor's note: [original picture of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3aKh.png).

Comment: It means what it says. Seem perfectly clear to me. Nothing there about subtraction or absolute values. Don't overthink this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function `round(val,p)` that rounds `val` to the nearest number with `p` significant digits (with the convention that if there is a tie, you round upwards). So round(0.9954,3) is  equal to 0.995 and round(0.9954,2)=1.0.

Another way to state your definition is that `x_approx` has `p` correct significant digits to `x` if `round(x,p)==round(x_approx,p)`.

If `x=3.14159` and `x_approx=3.141585` then you can say that x_approx has 6 correct digits, since `round(x,6)==3.14159==round(x_approx,6)`.

**Note** that this definition is problematic, as explained in the book, since if you have `x=.9949` and `x_approx=.9952` then `x_approx` is correct to 1 digit and three significant digits, but **NOT** correct to two significant digits, which is one of the reasons ***relative error*** is a preferred measurement of accuracy for approximations.

Answer (score 0):

1. > *an approximation x' to x*

   So you have two numbers, x' and x, and they're not (necessarily) the same. They probably differ somewhere.
2. > ... if x' and x round to the same number to p significant digits

   Pick a number *p*. Then we'll write out both x and x' to p digits.
   If the first p digits of x' and x are the same, we can say the approximation x' is *correct to p significant digits*.

Let's pick some concrete numbers.

- `x = π`
- `x' = 22/7`
- `p = 3`

Now, round each of x and x' to 3 significant digits. π becomes `3.14`and 22/7 is `3.14`. (I'm assuming you know how to round, since you didn't ask about that, and cut out the text explaining it).

So, we can say *as an approximation to π, 22/7 is correct to 3 significant digits*.

If we instead choose `p = 5`, we get

- `π -> 3.1416` (the real value is `3.141592....`)
- `22/7 -> 3.1429` (the real value is `3.142857...`)

so *as an approximation to π, 22/7 is **not** correct to 5 significant digits*.